# Posting complex object at once in REST api or progressively add subresources?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Let say you have a web service that is built by applying RESTful principles. You have a URL that you can POST a new Article too. `/articles` is the path.

Each article consists of a title, date, description, etc... (primitive values) as well as more complex relations like the categories the article should be placed in, location, etc.

When you do a GET for the resource after it is created on e.g. `/articles/123456` you get a response in JSON with all the primitive data like the title etc and simple fields that contain URLs for the location, categories etc. I do not embed those data in the article.

But what is the correct thing to do when you are creating a new article? Should I embed the categories, location etc (things that is more like relations to other compound objects) or should you first POST a new article with simple data then progressivly add data to it?

Such as `/articles/123456/categories POST`?

Or does this depend on the business requirements that states what data is required to create an article? What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

Having mutable sub-resources (or collections) could be useful, or not. Think about the API consumer, how will he want to use your API? Also think about the lifecycle of the associated resources; can those entities live on their own?  Considering these things should give you a fairly good idea of whether you need to be able to mutate those sub-resources/collections in their own right. Anyways, I'd say starting small, and POSTing those resources along with the article itself (and GETting them along with the article) in a sensible starting point. You can always add API methods to mutate/query sub-resources/collections later.

Answer (score 0):

I think using using multiple POSTs to update/create each entities is simpler. If you're trying to do everything in a 'big bang' you might have to write several code to split the form object into multiple entities before adding them.

For example, assuming you're creating a new post and assign it two tags. Your HTML form is like this

```
<form ..>
  <input name="postId" ../>
  <input name="subject" ../>
  <input name="content" ../>
  <input name="tagIds" value="1001"../>
  <input name="tagIds" value="1002"../>
</form>
```

(I believe) You cannot map this into Post and Tag entities in one go. So you have to create a form backing object that has all those properties:

```
public class NewPostForm {
  private long postid;
  private String subject;
  private String content;
  private List<String> tagIds;
  ..
}
```

Then before saving these into your persistence layer you have to slice them into a Post and Tags objects first.

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String createNewPost(@ModelAttribute(..) NewPostForm form,..) {
  Post newPost = .. // create post from form

  List<Tag> tags = .. // create tag collections from form

  // save through persistence layer
}
```

Whereas if you use separate POST per entity class you don't need this NewPostForm class.